# How to make all the Handlers(pages) on a google app engine website https

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi I want to make my all the handlers loaded as https in google app engine project. Can any one know a way to do it? is there a configuration which we could apply for all the handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use webapp2? With webapp2 you can specify the URI schemes allowed for a route:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/products', handler='handlers.ProductsHandler', name='products-list', schemes=['https'])
```

See: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

In your app.yaml, use `secure: always` for each of the handlers where you'd like to require https. For example:

```
handlers:

- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

You can [read more about the secure URLs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Secure_URLs) in the documentation.

Comment: Hey thank you Ill go through but I have around 100 urls and I want to know is there another way to do this rather than specifying all the URLs one by one on app.yaml